# Wrap list item creation in a for loop

Tags: vb.net

I have a class for `customers` with a property inside that is a `list(of orderdetails)`.

In my code when I want to add a customers order details I would do something like

```vb
customerclass.items = new list(customerclass.orderdetails) from {
    new customerclass.orderdetails with {
        .property1 = "example value"
        .property2 = "another example value"}}
```

This works absolutely fine with no issues.

However this only works for singular `orderdetails` per customer, ideally where I have a customer with let's say 2 `orderdetails` I wanted to somehow insert a

```vb
for x = 0 to orderdetailcounter.value ' (example 2)

    customerclass.items = new list(customerclass.orderdetails) from {
        new customerclass.orderdetails with {
            .property1 = "example value" & x
            .property2 = "another example value" & x}}

next
```

On 1st loop .property1 would be "example value 0", .property2 would be "another example value 0" and so-on.

So I'm effectively trying to iterate around and be able to create multiple order items for a given customer without having to hardcode the additional order items as there could be many per customer.

Comment: You are close create new orderdetails at the start and then add it to the items if its initialized if not initialize the `customerclass.items` outside the for loop.  To add each newaly crated object to list use `.Add` method.

Comment: You can declare a new `customerclass.orderdetails` using the same syntax as inside the `List` initializer, and add it to an existing list using `.Add`.

Comment: i must be doing something wrong with my code here as it doesn't append the additional items.  i think i need to do a customerclassb - add the orderedetails and then do customerclass.add(customerclassb) but i'm not getting very far.  Any additional help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Start with `customerclass.items.Add`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialise the collection in your declaration (or in the ctor) e.g.

```
Property Items As New List(Of OrderDetails)
```

Then use `.Add` inside the loop:

```
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim customerclass = New CustomerClass
    For x = 0 To 2
      customerclass.Items.Add(New CustomerClass.OrderDetails With {
                              .property1 = $"example value {x}",
                              .property2 = $"another example value {x}"})
    Next

    For Each orderdetails In customerclass.Items
      Console.WriteLine($"{orderdetails.property1}")
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("FINISHED")
    Console.ReadKey()
  End Sub

  Class CustomerClass
    Property Items As New List(Of OrderDetails)

    Public Class OrderDetails
      Property property1 As String
      Property property2 As String
    End Class
  End Class
End Module
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for this.  I'd missed the 'New List' in my class to start with but the code really helped in point out the correct flow of things.  Now working as intended, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```vb
parent.Children = Enumerable.Range(0, count)
                            .Select(Function(i) New Child With {.Name = $"Child{i}"})
                            .ToList()
```

`Enumerable.Range` creates an enumerable list of numbers and `Select` creates an item for each of those numbers - effectively an inline `For` loop.